Having a different Monolog conf when running Symfony CLI
In a nutshell:
My Symfony app is configured to emit errors messages to Slack. It is convenient to have those notifications when the app encounters an error while is it handling a user query.
But sometimes an admin runs a command with Symfony's ./bin/console <some_custom_command> and in this context I don't want to have Slack notification in case of errors [1].
How can I achieve it?

Some more details
my config/packages/monolog.yaml looks like this:
when@dev:
  # ... some conf used for my local development. Ofc it does not send anything to slack ...
when@prod:
  monolog:
    handlers:
      file:
        type: rotating_file
        level: info
        # some more conf for the file handler.
      slack:
        type: slack
        level: error
        # some more conf for the Slack handler

What I have in prod is hence: it logs all messages to a file + it also sends to Slack the messages when "severity is error".
What I would like to have in prod is: log all messages to a file + also send to Slack the messages "severity is error and PHP_SAPI == "cli""

What I tried
I looked into the handlers channel config, but if I understand correctly it cannot achieve what I want, because it makes it possible to filter based on the piece of code which emits the message, which is not what I want (since I want to filter based on the running context).
I'm afraid don't have any other leads.
[1]: because most of the time errors occurs because the admin messed up with his or her command so a Slack message would just be noise for me since there is not much I can do in this context. (Any anyway, if this error is due to a bug on my side, the admin can get in touch with us directly)
